# Existence of a set with given Hausdorff dimension

Tags: measure-theory

Today we had funny discussion whether one can extend the notion of homotopy groups for noninteger indices. Long story short, we asked ourself the following question:

> Let $d\in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$. Is it known, whether there exists a set $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{\lceil d \rceil}$ such that the Hausdorff dimension of $A$ is equal to $d$? In case this is true, could someone provide me with a reference please.

Comment: Try Geometric Measure Theory by Federer Herbert

Comment: @SoumikGhosh Thanks, I'll check it tomorrow in the library.

Comment: Are you already okay with the case $d < 1$ ?

Comment: @CharlesMadeline I am interested in anything you have for me :)

Comment: @SoumikGhosh telling someone to consult Federer is not wrong. Not nice either. Definitely amusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First step: answer the question for $0<d<1$**

Take a look at [some examples of deterministic fractals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fractals_by_Hausdorff_dimension#Deterministic_fractals). The image below is taken from wiki and quotes [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0911.2497.pdf), which studies dimensions $1$ and $3$. This is a well-known construction (see [fat Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set#Other_fat_Cantor_sets)).

[image: Fat Cantor]

**Second step: from dimension $1$ to $\lceil d \rceil$**

Just use induction and the following [result from Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/189270/hausdorff-dimension-of-r-x-x): given a separable space $X$ (for instance $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n$), $\mbox{dim}_H(X \times [0,1]) = \mbox{dim}_H(X) + 1$.

Now consider $d > 0$. If $d$ is an integer, just take $A = [0,1]^d$. Otherwise, write $d = \lfloor d \rfloor + \{d\}$. Thanks to the first step, as $0<\{d\}<1$, we have a Cantor set $C \subset [0,1]$ *s.t.* $\mbox{dim}_H(C) = \{d\}$. The previous result yields $\mbox{dim}(C \times [0,1]^{\lfloor d \rfloor}) = \lfloor d \rfloor + \{d\} = d$, via induction. And $A := C \times [0,1]^{\lfloor d \rfloor} \subset \mathbb{R}^{\lceil d \rceil}$.

Comment: Thanks. That is a very nice solution.