# Nested family of sets with given Hausdorff dimension

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Just before (namely here [Existence of a set with given Hausdorff dimension](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3142723/existence-of-a-set-with-given-hausdorff-dimension)) I asked whether one can find for any real number $\alpha>0$ a set $A_\alpha$ such that $A_\alpha$ has Hausdorff dimension $\alpha$. The answer was constructive and used fat Cantor sets and taking the cartesian product with some unit intervall. This made me wonder whether one could push this a bit further, namely

> Can we find a family of sets $(A_\alpha)_{\alpha>0}$ such that $A_\alpha$ has Hausdorff dimension $\alpha$, $A_n $ is homotopic to $[0,1]^n$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $A_\alpha\subset A_\beta$ for $\alpha < \beta$?

Comment: Interesting question ! Unlike in the link you mentioned, we cannot really consider the case $0<\alpha<1$ and then generalize with induction, because we would not be sure that $A_{\alpha} \subset A_{\beta}$ when $\alpha \to n^-$ and $\beta \to n^+$. Thinking about it

Comment: @CharlesMadeline I think the inclusion you describe are not problematic, as we can modify our family such that $A_{\gamma+1}:= A_\gamma \times [0;1] \cup [0;1]^{\lfloor \gamma \rfloor}\times \{0\}$. The thing I do not see is how we get inclusions for $0<\gamma<1$.

Comment: ah yes, that is right indeed. The Cantor sets are a priori not really nested ; what would suffice is a lemma like: if $A \subset B$ and $\mbox{dim}_H(A) < \mbox{dim}_H(B)$, then there exists $C$ with $A \subset C \subset B$ and $\mbox{dim}_H(A)<\mbox{dim}_H(C) < \mbox{dim}_H(C)$

Comment: @CharlesMadeline I am not quite sure whether that would suffice (as we are dealing with an uncountable family).

Comment: I think that would do. There is a classic exercise that says: if $f$ is a continuous function on $[0,1]$ such that for all $x<y$, there is $\lambda \in ]0,1[$ s.t. $f(\lambda x +(1-\lambda)y)\le $\lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y)$. Then $f$ is convex. In our case, you have a dense set of correct values $\alpha$. Take unions and conclude

Comment: @CharlesMadeline I don't understand what you mean. Surely we can use this lemma to construct a family $(A_\gamma)_{\gamma \in \mathbb{Q}}$, but I do not see how you get the remaining sets (or how convexity would help us, we are dealing with sets with certain properties, not with real numbers).

Comment: @severing schraven First you build a countable and dense set $D \subset ]0,1]$ s.t. $(A_{\gamma})_{\gamma \in D}$ is increasing and $\mbox{dim}_H(A_{\gamma})=\gamma$. Then define for all $\alpha$, $A_{\alpha} = \bigcup \limits_{\gamma < \alpha \\ \gamma \in D} A_{\gamma}$. I leave it to you to prove that $(A_{\alpha})$ is increasing (easy) and that $\mbox{dim}_H(A_{\alpha})=\alpha$ (use that Hausdorff dimension is increasing and introduce some sequence $\gamma_n \in D^{\mathbb{N}}$ converging to $\alpha$ from above...)

Comment: @CharlesMadeline Ah, sorry, I am stupid. Now I see what you meant. Thank you very much.

Comment: @CharlesMadeline I wrapped everything up in an answer. I hope it's fine for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is a wrap up of the comments by Charles Madeline and the reference given by Skeeve in this mathoverflow question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/325532/existence-of-subset-with-given-hausdorff-dimension.

In Theorem 5.6 from The Geometry of Fractal Sets by Falconer stating that for any Souslin space $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and any $0<\alpha < \text{dim}_H(A)$ there exists a compact set $K\subset A$ such that $\alpha= \text{dim}_H(K)$.

From this we get that for all Souslin spaces $A\subset B \subseteq [0;1]$ and any $\gamma \in (\text{dim}_H(A); \text{dim}_H(B)) $ there exists $A\subseteq C \subseteq B$ such that $\text{dim}_H(C)= \gamma$.

Indeed, this follows from the fact that $B\setminus A$ is a Souslin space again and that $\dim_H(B\setminus A)= \dim_H(B)$ as $\dim_H(B) = \dim_H(B\setminus A \cup A)= \max\{ \dim_H(B\setminus A), \dim_H(A) \}$. This allows us to construct (by induction) a family $(A_\alpha)_{\alpha\in [0;1]\cap \mathbb{Q}}$ sucht that $A_\alpha \subset A_\beta$ for $\alpha<\beta$ and $\dim_H(A_\alpha)= \alpha$. Furthermore, we may choose $A_1 = [0;1]$.

Finally we define for $\gamma \in [0;1]$
$$ A_\gamma = \bigcup_{\alpha \in [0;\gamma]\cap \mathbb{Q}} A_\alpha $$
then we get
$$ \dim_H(A_\gamma) = \dim_H\left( \bigcup_{\alpha \in [0;\gamma]\cap \mathbb{Q}} A_\alpha \right) = \sup_{\alpha \in [0;\gamma]\cap \mathbb{Q}} \dim_H(A_\alpha) = \gamma. $$
This family satisfies all the conditions we want. Identifying $[0;1]$ with $[0;1]\times \{0 \}$ we play the same game for $\gamma \in [1;2]$, respectively with similar identification for all $\gamma \in [0,\infty)$ (we could also use the construction suggested by Charles Madeline in the comments taking the cartesian product with the unit interval to pass from $[n; n+1]$ to $[n+1;n+2]$).